# How to give router's wifi clients access to WIFI clients of another sub router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have an internet router (Main) which has internet access. Another router B's (WAN port) is connected to its Ethernet port.

`WIFI IP address of main router is 192.168.10.1, its clients are assigned 192.168.10.X`

`Second router B : Wifi address IP address scheme 192.168.168.1 and clients are assigned 192.168.168.N`

Is it possible to access client 192.168.168.N by the clients of main router whose IP's are like 192.168.10.N ???

Please help.

Comment: wifi bridge and set client IP address to one private network subset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. you can do this.

1. Hook up a LAN port (not WAN) of Router B to the network. This is important.
2. I give Router B a static IP address on the network. This prevents it getting lost or misconfigured on a restart of the network.
3. On router B, turn DHCP OFF.

Now router B is an extension of your network as you desire.

I have this setup with my two routers (Cisco VPN Main and Cisco Wireless sub-router)

Comment: as sample: MikroTik RB2011UiAS-2HnD-IN or MikroTik CRS109-8G-1S-2HnD-IN may NAT routing internal network. But wifi bridge or repeater wifi better.

Comment: Thank you so much dear, it worked amazingly

Comment: You are most welcome and I was pleased to help

Comment: it actually worked at the time, now devices are struggling getting IP address from sub router B, (I have disabled DHCP in this router but still). Is there any other setting that I need to turn off in router B ? IGMP snooping etc  perhaps??

Comment: DHCP is OFF on router B and that is fine. Review your LAN settings to make sure it has 192.168.10.x static IP on the network. Then restart BOTH Routers and upon restart ensure any device on Router B gets a proper IP. You may want to / need to remake the Wireless Profile on Router B.